# Bar Code Scanning

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using Zxing Lib to scan QR and Bar code. My code is working very well for QR code but unfortunately it is nor working for Bar code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Any help will really appreciable. In my App i can not use InTENTINTEGRATOR

In zxing LIB Following format is provided-

```
       static final Collection<BarcodeFormat> PRODUCT_FORMATS;
       static final Collection<BarcodeFormat> ONE_D_FORMATS;
       static final Collection<BarcodeFormat> QR_CODE_FORMATS =         EnumSet.of(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
    static final Collection<BarcodeFormat> DATA_MATRIX_FORMATS = EnumSet.of(BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX);
     static {
    PRODUCT_FORMATS = EnumSet.of(BarcodeFormat.UPC_A,
                             BarcodeFormat.UPC_E,
                             BarcodeFormat.EAN_13,
                             BarcodeFormat.EAN_8,
                             BarcodeFormat.RSS_14);
ONE_D_FORMATS = EnumSet.of(BarcodeFormat.CODE_39,
                           BarcodeFormat.CODE_93,
                           BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
                           BarcodeFormat.ITF);
ONE_D_FORMATS.addAll(PRODUCT_FORMATS);
```

}

Comment: You haven't defined "not working"! Why can't you use IntentIntegrator? It just does exactly what you posted, more or less, and does it correctly.

Comment: @SeanOwen.. thanks for your response. When i use IntentIntegrator then it will ask user to install barcode scnner ( third party App) but in my app there should not be any third party App

Comment: Er, why are you using Intents then? this is only for accessing third-party apps.

Comment: @ Sean Owen... First of all thank for your sincere response. I know that you are among one of Zxing developer .Your work for zxing is really praiseworthy . When i execute my aap with above code it not create any notification to install barcode scanner , without installation QR Code is scanning Successfully , then in same manner why not it work for bar code.

Comment: I dont understand this. This code does not execute your app. it executes mine.

Comment: @ Sean.. is it possible to make standalone scanner with IntentIntegrator , that can QR code and bar code both?

Comment: Its possible to make your own standalone app. But this is not related to Intents. if you can't make an app I strongly suggest you just use Intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing the scan mode. Try something like :

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
```

or

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
```

You can find more info on the following page: 
https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java

Comment: @ Sandyiscool ... Thanks for your quick response , but form last 3 days i.e 72 hr i searched all blog and tutorial .. Noting is work for me... Even your Suggestion is not working for me... I am in a great mess ... PLZ help me

Comment: Did you try not setting any explicit format at all, i.e., sending the intent without manually setting the "SCAN_MODE" property ? If the barcode you are trying to read is conformant to the standard barcode formats mentioned by zxing library, then it should read it fine.

Comment: @sandy... yeap i solved my problem , but by intentIntegrator. that is my compromise with  issue.Not able to create Standalone App to scan bar code. but in future i will try to develop a standalone app for bar code . Thanks for your response form my bottom of heart

Comment: @BlueGreen : Great to hear that you finally managed to find an alternative :) Intent integrator is the recommended way by zxing to integrate barcode scanning into your app.Nevertheless, if you follow through the zxing barcode scanner app's source code, you can adopt and modify the code depending on your requirements and can make a standalone barcode/QR code scanning app.

Comment: @sandy.... yes i will modify Zxing LIB according to my requirement to scan bar code. Then i will inform you that i find a permanent solution. Ryt now i am quite busy in other App. Thanks again. you are such a nice man.

Answer (score 1):

you use this for barcode scan

```
private void drawResultPoints(Bitmap barcode, Result rawResult) {
    ResultPoint[] points = rawResult.getResultPoints();
    if (points != null && points.length > 0) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(barcode);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.result_points));
        if (points.length == 2) {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4.0f);
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[0], points[1]);
        } else if (points.length == 4
                && (rawResult.getBarcodeFormat() == BarcodeFormat.UPC_A || rawResult
                        .getBarcodeFormat() == BarcodeFormat.EAN_13)) {
            // Hacky special case -- draw two lines, for the barcode and
            // metadata
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[0], points[1]);
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[2], points[3]);
        } else {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
            for (ResultPoint point : points) {
                canvas.drawPoint(point.getX(), point.getY(), paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also check this

```
 private boolean encodeContentsFromZXingIntent(Intent intent) {
 // Default to QR_CODE if no format given.
String formatString = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT);
format = null;
if (formatString != null) {
  try {
    format = BarcodeFormat.valueOf(formatString);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    // Ignore it then
  }
}
if (format == null || format == BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE) {
  String type = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE);
  if (type == null || type.length() == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  this.format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
  encodeQRCodeContents(intent, type);
} else {
  String data = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA);
  if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
    contents = data;
    displayContents = data;
    title = activity.getString(R.string.contents_text);
  }
}
return contents != null && contents.length() > 0;
```

}

Comment: @ Maya ,, your response is really appreciable , but i am asking for Scan Bar Code with Zxing LIB

Comment: format is already define in ZXing Lib. So why we define here??

Comment: This has nothing to do with scanning barcodes. It has something to do with encoding them.

Comment: @ Sean... so in your view what must be here , which make me to scan bar code